# Why won't my docker container start when I have an ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to include an ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile. It seems simply having this line in my Dockerfile causes the container not to start.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ unixodbc-dev # pyodbc build dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev -y


WORKDIR /test

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY *.py ./
COPY *.txt ./
COPY Dockerfile ./
COPY vars.sh /etc/profile.d/
COPY entrypoint.sh ./

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/test/entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "Hello World"]  # <---- Container starts when this line is commented out. Will not start when this command is executed. 

CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

I run the following command to build.

```
sudo docker run --network host -d -p 8080:8080 test
```

Output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  28.67kB
Step 1/15 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> 415775fb4b1f
Step 2/15 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ unixodbc-dev # pyodbc build dependencies
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 20615c0701e8
Step 3/15 : RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5dacb381b06
Step 4/15 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y apt-transport-https &&     curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - &&     curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list &&     apt-get update &&     ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 876d4ef82bf8
Step 5/15 : WORKDIR /test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d714c96591e
Step 6/15 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d82824171e5
Step 7/15 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b41de5e83e64
Step 8/15 : COPY *.py ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9dbe93e3c805
Step 9/15 : COPY *.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 30307de43e5d
Step 10/15 : COPY Dockerfile ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2124fd93147
Step 11/15 : COPY vars.sh /etc/profile.d/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d739f473c579
Step 12/15 : COPY entrypoint.sh ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be484c119b6a
Step 13/15 : RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/test/entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea6a12927a70
Step 14/15 : ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "Hello World"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c6e7fc7acc12
Step 15/15 : CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad685c22eee9
Successfully built ad685c22eee9
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Then running the command to start the container

```
sudo docker run --network host -d -p 8080:8080 test
```

Then to see what containers are running

```
sudo docker container list
```

Output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Nothing is running!

If I comment out the ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile and build, the container will run. It also doesn't matter what I put in the ENTRYPOINT. In my example above, I tried just a "Hello World". My intention is to have the ENTRYPOINT run a script that will set some environmental variables (see below). I am aware I could set them directly in the Dockerfile, but I would like to avoid doing that.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile.d/vars.sh
```

If someone knows why including ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile won't let a container run, or what I can do to investigate further, please let me know. Alternatively, if someone knows a better way to set environment variables from a file using Dockerfile (not docker-compose.yml), please let me know as well.

Comment: Potentially dumb question, but I'm not where I can run, just comment. Are you sure you can `echo` in your env when you get into bash without the `ENTRYPOINT` defined?

Comment: @ViaTech, I am not sure if you can or not. I saw it on another post. It doesn't seem to matter what I put there. ENTRYPOINT["/test/entrypoint.sh"] gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container only runs a single process, and then exits.  If the image contains both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, [the command is passed as additional arguments to the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  If you run your image without a `-d` option, so it runs in the foreground, I expect you will see the output

```
Hello World python3 app.py
```

as the result of combining these two sets of options.

> ... run a script that will set some [environment] variables ...

Since the command is passed to the entrypoint as parameters, the usual thing to do is to end your entrypoint script with `exec "$@"`, which replaces the entrypoint with whatever command is in those positional parameters.  So I'd write your example as

```bash
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/profile.d/vars.sh
exec "$@"
```

using the standard [`.`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/dot.html) shell builtin to read the file, rather than the non-standard `source`.

Since a container doesn't usually use shell dotfiles at all, depending on your setup, you could also put `export` commands directly in the entrypoint wrapper script, and they will survive through switching to the command.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the 'exec "$@"' portion? I am probably misunderstanding something. I tried this and while the container now runs, it does not set the environment variables in either script.  (entrypoint.sh or vars.sh).  I do see however that the command under COMMAND points to /test/entrypoint.sh.

Comment: If you run `./entrypoint.sh python3 app.py`, for example, then `exec "$@"` at the end of `entrypoint.sh` will run `python3 app.py`.

Comment: Note that, if you're `docker inspect`ing the container, what that shows as the environment is only what Docker knows about from `docker run -e` and Compose `environment:` settings; it is not necessarily the actual environment of the process in the container.

Comment: I can confirm that app.py is running, however the environment variables in entrypoint.sh are getting set and then stomped. I added "env > test.txt" to entrypoint.sh. When I log into the container via "sudo docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash" and view test.txt, I see the variables have been set. When I run "env" from the container's command line, they are missing again.

Comment: They are set in the environment of the main container process.  `docker exec` starts an additional process that isn't a child of the main process, and also won't show those variables.  If your application code inspects its own environment, it will see the values that are set in the entrypoint script.

Comment: That explains it! I just added some code to allow me to inspect this. Sure enough those variables are present! Thank you for all of your help!